# Part of an image removed when dividing an image into sub images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image of 336*104 pixels and I need to divide it into 35*35 sub images. However 336 and 104 are not divisible by 35, therefore a part of the image is removed when I divide it. I get a re-assembled image without the parts which are not of 35*35 pixels.  I can't resize it because the image is very different if I do it.  Here my code:

```
% Size of the image
[H W] = size(im);

% Each sub image has 35*35 pixels
size_sub_image = 35;

% Size of each sub image
H_divided = H/size_sub_image;
W_divided = W/size_sub_image;

% Reminders allowing to take the images which are not divided
R_H = rem(H,size_sub_image);
R_W = rem(W,size_sub_image);

%Variable which is incremented and stand for each sub image
nbr_sub_images = 1;  

% Division of the image into sub images    
for i = 1:floor(H_divided)
    for j = 1:floor(W_divided)

        % R_H and R_W allow to create the sub images reminding, which have not
        %35*35 pixels. 
        %My idea was that when each i or j reach the max in the loop, the 
        %algorithm take the remindind images which have the size of R_H or R_W.
        % R_H = 21 (336 = 35*9+21) and R_W = 34 (104 = 35*2+34)

        if (i ~= floor(H_divided) && j ~= floor(W_divided))   

            nbr_sub_images = nbr_sub_images + 1;
            im_divided(:,:,nbr_sub_images) = im(size_sub_image*(i-1)+1:size_sub_image*i ,size_sub_image*(j-1)+1:size_sub_image*j );   

        end 

        if (i == floor(H_divided))

            nbr_sub_images = nbr_sub_images + 1;      
            im_divided(:,:,nbr_sub_images) = im(size_sub_image*(i-1)+1:size_sub_image*i ,size_sub_image*(j-1)+1:size_sub_image*j );

            nbr_sub_images = nbr_sub_images + 1;      
            im_divided(:,:,nbr_sub_images) = im(size_sub_image*i+1:size_sub_image*i + R_H,size_sub_image*(j-1)+1:size_sub_image*j);

        end

        if (j == floor(W_divided))

            nbr_sub_images = nbr_sub_images + 1;   
            im_divided(:,:,nbr_sub_images) = im(size_sub_image*(i-1)+1:size_sub_image*i ,size_sub_image*(j-1)+1:size_sub_image*j );

            nbr_sub_images = nbr_sub_images + 1;   
            im_divided(:,:,nbr_sub_images) = im(size_sub_image*(i-1)+1:size_sub_image*i,size_sub_image*j+1:size_sub_image*j + R_W);                 


        end

    end
end
```

When I execute it, i get the error: "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch", but I don't understand why because when I remove the `R_H` and `R_W`, the code works perfectly.

Comment: At what line does the error occur ? What do you mean by remove `R_H` and `R_W` ?

Comment: The error occurs at the " im_divided(:,:,nbr_sub_images) = im(size_sub_image*(i-1)+1:size_sub_image*i,size_sub_image*j+1:size_sub_image*j + R_W); " line, when j = floor(W_divided) and i = 1. 

If I don't use R_H and R_W in the code (by putting the conditions if( i == floor(H_divided) ) and if (j == floor(N_divided) in comments for example) , it executes perfectly, but the image is therefore cropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you are trying to put sub-images of different sizes into a 3-D array, which is not going to work. When you add 2-D images to your array `im_divided`, the first and second dimension have to be the same (i.e. 35x35) for all sub-images. For more information, see the [MATLAB documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html).

There are 2 possible solutions: Either you pad the edges of your image (with zeroes or some other value) so that width and height are divisible by 35, or you use a cell array to store your sub-images:

```
im_divided{nbr_sub_images} = im(rows, columns)
```

Cell arrays are capable of storing matrices of different sizes (or in fact all kinds of different objects).